# c++ returning the value of an object inside a map

Tags: c++

my problem is that i've a very basic Node class:

```cpp
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    int value;
    int key;
    Node(Node* p, Node* n, int k, int val) :prev(p), next(n), key(k), 
value(val) {};
    Node(int k, int val) :prev(NULL), next(NULL), key(k), value(val) {};
};
```

Then a Cache class that stores a map of Node objects

```cpp
class Cache {
protected:
    map<int, Node*> mp; //map the key to the node in the linked list
    int cp;  //capacity
    Node* tail; // double linked list tail pointer
    Node* head; // double linked list head pointer
    virtual void set(int, int) = 0; //set function
    virtual int get(int) = 0; //get function

};
```

Finally I've a LRUCache class that's derived from Cache class.

```cpp
class LRUCache : public Cache {
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity) { cp = capacity; }
    virtual int get(int k) {
        std::map<int, Node*>::iterator it;
        it = mp.find(k);

        if (it != mp.end()) {
            return it->second->value;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    virtual void set(int k, int v) {
        if (mp[k]) {
            mp[k] = new Node(k, v);
        }
        else {
            std::map<int, Node*>::iterator it = mp.begin();
            mp.insert(it, std::pair<int, Node*>(k, new Node(k, v)));
        }
    }
};
```

The error I'm experiencing is on the getter of this LRUCache class.

Returning this: "return it->second->value" gives me this error:

LRUCache.exe: 0xC0000005: Memory Access Violation while reading the path  0x00000008.

Why should it return me an error if the member value "value" is public on the Node struct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't update the cache when a node is removed, most likely. This is a run-time error, it has nothing to do with access specifiers.

Comment: Also, why a convoluted linked list that holds a `int -> int` mapping? Just use `std::map<int, int>` or a `std::unordered_map<int, int>`.

Comment: Your whole `set` function can be replaced by `mp[k] = new Node(k, v);`, but you should delete the old one (or use `unique_ptr`), the `it` argument of `insert` is just a hint for insertion, not the real position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (mp[k]) {
        mp[k] = new Node(k, v);
    }
    else {
        std::map<int, Node*>::iterator it = mp.begin();
        mp.insert(it, std::pair<int, Node*>(k, new Node(k, v)));
    }
```

There are two possibilities there. If the map entry at `k` already exists and refers to a non-null `Node`, that `Node` is leaked and replaced with another `Node` (which makes little sense, but at least it doesn't immediately lead to crashing).

If the map entry doesn't exist, then `mp[k]` implicitly creates one, with `nullptr` as the value (it's also possible that it already exists and holds a null pointer; the end result is the same). You then proceed to call `mp.insert()` with the same key `k` - that does nothing, because the entry already exists. A `Node` is leaked here once again - but the main problem is that null pointer in the map.

When you next call `get()` with the same key, it retrieves the null pointer and promptly attempts to dereference it. That's where your program is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Igor, as you said the problem was in the setter.

this refactor seems to work:

```cpp
    if (mp.find(k) != mp.end()) {
        auto it = mp[k];
        it->value = v;
    }
    else {
        auto it = mp.begin(); 
        mp.insert(it, std::pair<int, Node*>(k, new Node(k, v)));
    }
```